# UITextField doesn't get cursor when UITableView scrolles to not visible cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I have a custom grouped TableView with 5 sections and in total with 50 custom cells of type:

```
Label      |    XXX
```

where XXX can be UITextField, UITextView, UIButton, UILabel. Cells have mixed order in tableView.

[image]

To navigate through textFields & textViews i added Next/Prev buttons on my keyboard.

[image]

**The problem** is the when i select txtField and **click Next or Prev button**, the table scrolls to the needed cell position, but **txtField doesn't get the cursor**. In order to get the cell with textField/textView i use:

```
 nextCell = [self tableView:_myTableView 
      cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:curRow inSection:curSec]];
```

I need to search through all cells in tableView, not only through the visible ones.

As i tested, the problem is in this line of code, because if i call:

```
nextCell = [_myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:curRow inSection:curSec]];
```

and the cell is visible, then the txtField gets cursor. However, if i need to jump from cell (section = 1, row = 6) to cell (section =0, row = 3) which is not visible, i get nil.

My full code of button function:

```
-(void) previousTextField:(id)sender
{
   int curTagInd = _editingTextElement.tag;

   NSIndexPath *curInd = [self getRowIndexOf:_editingTextElement];
   int curSec = curInd.section;
   int curRow = curInd.row;

   id nextView = nil;
   UITableViewCell *nextCell = nil;

   do {        
    curRow--;

    if (curRow >=0) {
        nextCell = [self tableView:_myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:curRow inSection:curSec]];//[_myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:--curRow inSection:curInd.section]];
        curTagInd--;
        if ([nextCell isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]] || [nextCell isKindOfClass:[CustomLongTextCell class]]) {
            do {
                nextView = [nextCell viewWithTag:curTagInd];
                if ([nextView isEnabled]) {
                    nextCell = nil;
                    _editingIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:curRow inSection:curSec];
                    break;
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            } while (nextView != nil && ((![nextView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && ![nextView isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])  || ![nextView isEnabled]));
        }
      }
      else if(curSec > 0){ //got to previous section
        curSec--;
        curRow = [self getNumberOfRowsInSection:curSec];
        curTagInd = [self getNumberOfRowsInSection:curSec]+1;
      }
      else{
        nextCell = nil;
      }

   } while (nextCell != nil);

   if (nextView != nil) {
      [self.myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:_editingIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];

      UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)nextView;
      [textField becomeFirstResponder];
   }
}
```

Using this code i get inside method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`, but not in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

The problem was that the table began scrolling only after the function `previousTextField:` was finished, and thus, `[textField becomeFirstResponder];` was called before the table was scrolled to the needed position. Due to the fact that needed cell is still not visible on the screen, delegate methods didn't call.

To avoid this, i added timer after table-scrolling line:

```
NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.2
                                              target: self
                                            selector:@selector(doneScrolling)
                                            userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
```

and defined `doneScrolling` like:

```
-(void)doneScrolling
{
    NSLog(@"done scrolling");
    [self tableView:self.myTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:self.editingIndexPath];
}
```

where:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO]; 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    UIView *nextView = [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row+1];
    if ([nextView isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]] || [nextView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        if ([nextView isEnabled]) {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)nextView;
            [textField becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }  
 }
```